# How to add radio button in Boolean field in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Custom user model. When I go to signup form when I select the checkbox select these their boolean field. I want to restrict in the Boolean field in which the user can select only one Boolean field in signup form. I want to add a radio button in Boolean fields. Is there is a way to add a radio button in the boolean field?

[image]

***Forms.py***

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =  [
                "name",
                "username",
                "email",
                "password",
                
                'is_superuser',
                'is_Customer',
                'is_Service_Provider'


        ]       
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_superuser'  : forms.CheckboxInput('input_type' == 'radio'),
            'is_Service_Provider'   :forms.CheckboxInput('input_type' == 'radio'),
            'is_Customer' : forms.RadioSelect(),
            

        }
```

***Models.py***

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_Customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_Service_Provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator( regex = r'^\+?1?\d{9,10}$', message = "Phone number must be in the form of =919999999999")
    phone  = models.CharField('Phone', validators = [phone_regex], max_length=254, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % self.pk

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: for which field you have to implement that

Comment: in is_superuser, is_service_provider, is_Customer field

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have one form field and have the 3 different options as choices:

```
isSuperUser = 'Is Superuser'
isCustomer = 'Is Customer' 
isServiceProvider = 'Is Service Provider'

User_choices = (
    (isSuperUser, 'Is Superuser'),
    (isCustomer, 'Is Customer'),
    (isServiceProvider, 'Is Service Provider')
)
```

Then in your forms:

```
Usertype = forms.MultipleChoiceFieldChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=User_choices)
```

More info in the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget